Animation graph with plotly and PyQt5
I'm trying to produce an animated graph with plotly and display it in pyqt5 windows.
I use QWebEngineView() to desplay a graph in Pyqt5.
code :
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import plotly.io as pio

# Génération des données (exemple simplifié)
x_range = np.arange(1, 1251)  # x allant de 1 à 1250
t_range = np.arange(0, 3600)  # t allant de 0 à 3599 secondes

# Fonction fictive pour générer des vitesses
def generate_speed(x, t):
    # Exemple : une vitesse qui varie sinusoïdalement
    return 50 + 50 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x / 1250 + 2 * np.pi * t / 3600)

# Créer les données dans un DataFrame
data = {'x': [], 't': [], 'vitesse': []}
for t in t_range:
    for x in x_range:
        data['x'].append(x)
        data['t'].append(t)
        data['vitesse'].append(generate_speed(x, t))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Création des frames pour l'animation
frames = []
for t in t_range:
    frame_data = df[df['t'] == t]
    frames.append(go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(x=frame_data['x'], y=frame_data['vitesse'],
                                            mode='lines', name=f't={t}s')],
                           name=str(t)))

# Données initiales pour le graphe
initial_data = df[df['t'] == 0]

# Création de la figure
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Scatter(x=initial_data['x'], y=initial_data['vitesse'],
                     mode='lines', name='Initial')],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Vitesse en fonction de x avec le temps",
        xaxis=dict(title='x'),
        yaxis=dict(title='Vitesse'),
        updatemenus=[{
            'buttons': [
                {
                    'args': [None, {'frame': {'duration': 10, 'redraw': True}, 'fromcurrent': True}],
                    'label': 'Play',
                    'method': 'animate'
                },
                {
                    'args': [[None], {'frame': {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False}, 'mode': 'immediate',
                                      'transition': {'duration': 0}}],
                    'label': 'Pause',
                    'method': 'animate'
                }
            ],
            'direction': 'left',
            'pad': {'r': 10, 't': 87},
            'showactive': False,
            'type': 'buttons',
            'x': 0.1,
            'xanchor': 'right',
            'y': 0,
            'yanchor': 'top'
        }]
    ),
    frames=frames
)

# Convertir la figure en HTML
html = pio.to_html(fig, full_html=False)
print(" Affichage terminé")
# Créer l'application PyQt5
class PlotlyViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Plotly Viewer")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        web_view = QWebEngineView()
        web_view.setHtml(html)
        layout.addWidget(web_view)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewer = PlotlyViewer()
    viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


when running the code, I have nothing displayed in my Pyqt5 window.
But if i want to display a simple message like "Hello, World!" , it's worked.
Thank you for your help.

With your "Hello world" example do you mean that you tried to use that in the HTML? Try removing the full_html=False argument. Also, what is the size of the produced HTML? If it's more than 2mb it won't work (as explained in the setHtml() documentation, then see Use QWebEngineView to Display Something Larger Than 2MB?.
